# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

An increment could not be made on the corresponding values of the dictionary elements

```
sentiment_words = {}
for word in TotalVector:
    if not word in sentiment_words:
        sentiment_words[word]=(0,0,0)
        #sentiment_word(positive,negative,neutral)
    if ispositive(word):
        sentiment_words[word][0] += 1
    elif isnegative(word):
        sentiment_words[word][1] += 1
    elif isneutral(word):
        sentiment_words[word][2] += 1

print sentiment_words
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python `tuples` are immutable. Use `list` instead. Like:

```
sentiment_words[word]=[0,0,0]
```

And then convert to tuples:

```
sentiment_words = tuple(sentiment_words)
```